"SQLSTATE[08001]: TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out using Doctrine with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
I am encountering a timeout error when attempting to connect to SQL Server using Doctrine DBAL with the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server in my Laravel application. Here's the error log:
{
  "logtime": "2024-12-20 15:47:26.360",
  "message": "SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.",
  "context": {
    "exception": {
      "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception",
      "message": "SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.",
      "code": 8001,
      "file": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\SFI.BE\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception.php:18",
      "previous": {
        "class": "PDOException",
        "message": "SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.",
        "code": 8001,
        "file": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\SFI.BE\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:40"
      }
    }
  },
  "level": 400,
  "level_name": "ERROR",
  "channel": "local",
  "datetime": {
    "date": "2024-12-20 15:47:26.360454",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "Asia/Jakarta"
  },
  "extra": {
    "ip": "791-VM-2342",
    "ipserver": "791-VM-2342"
  }
}

Environtmen:

Laravel Framework

Doctrine DBAL

Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

SQL Server 2019

Running on Windows Server


It's happen in my production server
Steps Taken:

Verified that the SQL Server is up and running.

Tested the connection using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) — the connection works fine.

Ensured the ODBC Driver 17 is installed on the server.

Verified the firewall rules and ensured the correct ports (1433) are open.


Questions:

What could cause the "TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out" error in this context?

Are there specific configurations in Doctrine DBAL or Laravel's database config that I should check to prevent this issue?

Could this be related to SQL Server or network settings? If so, how can I troubleshoot further?



What edition of SQL Server 2019 is it? SQL Server 2019 Express, for example, often isn't even listening on TCP/IP ports by default and, even when it is, it's using a dynamic port that must be resolved through the SQL Browser service using its instance name with something like ServerNameOrIpAddress\SQLEXPRESS.

@AlwaysLearning it's just ip address and is it related to timeout error?

That smells like a network error.  So troubleshoot ip connectivity from the server.
